# Can't add same item to DataGrid twice, even if I delete the item before adding it again

Tags: javascript, dojo

If I add an item to my DataGrid, then delete it, then try to add it again, I get this error:

```
assertion failed in ItemFileWriteStore
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

I'm using Dojo 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try to add an item that was removed from a store without calling `save()` on the store you'll get this error. Stores have an 'un-delete' feature. check the ItemFileWriteStore API for `isDirty()` and `save()`.

Answer (score 0):

no two items in the store can have the same identifier at any point of time..